# Short и его памяять

Tags: kotlin, типы-данных

Прочитал в каком-то учебнике, что переменная **short** хранит 2 байта памяти.

И у меня возник следующий вопрос.

2 байта какой памяти?

ОЗУ, ПЗУ или память на HDD?

Пытался найти ответ в учебниках, но там про это ничего не сказано.

Comment: Переменная - она в памяти. Диск отпадает. Переменная может менять значение. ПЗУ отпадает. Остался один вариант...

Comment: Можно было просто сказать ОЗУ)))

Comment: Любой памяти. Берём любые два байта рядом в ОЗУ - это short. Берём любые два байта рядом в ПЗУ - это short. Последовательность двух байт можно представить в типом short, который означает число от -32768 до 32767, а ещё бывет unsigned short, бывает 16-битный float который на новых ЦП не используется. Бывает wchar_t.

Comment: *Можно было просто сказать ОЗУ)))* А вот нельзя! Минимальная длина комментария - 15 символов.

Comment: Шорт хранит 2 байта в ОЗУ я все правильно понял?

Comment: Если вы берёте специальный редактор, например IDA pro, или hiew - то вы можете на диске short найти.

Comment: short ничего не хранит. short - это представление данных, о котором договорились, что такая последовательность данных представлена определённым числом.

Comment: *я все правильно понял?* Нет. Вы спрашивали про ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ.  А short вообще - это тип данных, который нигде ничего не хранит, он просто есть.

Comment: А, да, переменная всегда в ОЗУ.

Comment: Short не *хранит* два байта памяти, он *занимает* два байта памяти.

Comment: Я имел в виду переменную с типом шорт.

Comment: Переменная всегда ОЗУ, short - всегда 2 байта.

Comment: А какая разница между хранить 2 байта памяти и занимать 2 байта памяти)?

Comment: Переменная типа `short` занимает два байта памяти, а хранит она то, что вы туда запишете, при условии, что оно не больше двух байт. Можете хранить один бит, можете 10, можете два байта.

Comment: Это синонимы???

Comment: Кто синонимы???

Comment: Ну тогда уж "данные этой переменной занимают в ОЗУ 2 байта". *какая разница между хранить 2 байта памяти и занимать 2 байта памяти)?* А я могу там хранить один единственный бит информации. Но занимать оно будет всё одно два байта.

Comment: Хранит ОЗУ, ПЗУ, Диск, а short - это... считайте метод шифрования. Шифровку можно хранить усно, на диске, в памяти. Одну и ту же информацию можно шифровать (представлять) разными методами. Для short можно выписать таблицу соответствия (шифрования), в которой будет 65536 строк.

Comment: То есть, short в любом случае займет 2 байта памяти  в ОЗУ, даже если я в short  впишу данные в размере 1 байта?

Comment: Даже если запишете туда 1 бит.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113631/discussion-on-question-by--short---).

Answer (score 1):

Язык Kotlin, который вы в тегах упомянули, не специфирует ничего о том, в каком носителе информации содержится есть стековая память и куча.

Java Virtual Machine, на которой обычно запускают скомпилированные программы на Kotlin тоже [не специфирует](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html) физический носитель, абстрагируясь от него, но гарантируя некоторой свойств памяти программы, особенно в свете многопоточного программирования.

Ну а если говорить о реальности, то обычно вся память все-таки хранится в [ОЗУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) за вычетом ситуаций, когда она переполняется и ОС выполняет [свопинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86).